# Localize the literal "today"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, localization, internationalization

Is it possible to localize the literal "today" in objective c/cocoa touch? That is when I display "today" a english iphone would get "today", a german would get "heute" and so forth.

Similar to the automatic handling of "monday", "tuesday" and so forth in NSDateFormatter.

Comment: The `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:` method of NSDateFormatter may help you.  [The docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contain an example for French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution came from the comment by user [aBitObvious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467105/abitobvious).

And as [aBitObvious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467105/abitobvious) said, it is to use the method `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:` in `NSDateFormatter`. There is an example in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) .